# bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use) on docker

Tags: docker, nginx

### Appears after starting the container

```js
2019/03/09 17:33:58 [emerg] 81#0: still could not bind()
2019/03/09 17:34:01 [emerg] 82#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2019/03/09 17:34:01 [emerg] 82#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2019/03/09 17:34:01 [emerg] 82#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2019/03/09 17:34:01 [emerg] 82#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2019/03/09 17:34:01 [emerg] 82#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
```

### Dockerfile content View github address

https://github.com/zhengxidong/docker/blob/master/lnp7.2_supervisord_dockerfile/Dockerfile

Using `supervisord` to start multiple services.Nginx configuration file configuration `daemon off;` no error log appears, why is this?If you remove the `daemon off;`, No above error.

Comment: You share not enough information. Share entire Dockerfile

Comment: What is your nginx and supervisord configuration?

Comment: @ozlevka 已添加完整的dockerfile，Added the full dockerfile, please help me see what is the reason, remove the `daemon off; `then the error log appears

Comment: @Mostafa Hussein The full dockerfile address is attached, and the supervisord is configured in the dockerfile

Comment: use some other port , like 8080

Comment: @Ijaz Ahmad Khan My development is to use mapping other ports，-v 8787:80

Answer (score 1):

You have run nginx twice:

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 01:27 pts/0    00:00:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/supervisord
root         9     1  0 01:27 pts/0    00:00:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
root        10     1  0 01:27 pts/0    00:00:00 php-fpm: master process (/usr/local/php/etc/php-fpm.conf)
root        11     1  0 01:27 pts/0    00:00:00 /usr/sbin/crond -n
root        12     1  0 01:27 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx <=============== Here
nginx       13    12  0 01:27 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
nobody      14    10  0 01:27 pts/0    00:00:00 php-fpm: pool www
nobody      15    10  0 01:27 pts/0    00:00:00 php-fpm: pool www
root        68     0  0 01:29 pts/1    00:00:00 /bin/bash
root        84     1  0 01:29 pts/0    00:00:00 /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx <=== And Here
root        85    68  0 01:29 pts/1    00:00:00 ps -ef
```

The second nginx failed to run because the first is already run.

N.B.

I suggest you read [the best practices](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/) writing Dockerfile. Your image creating during 10-15 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

It means nginx or some other process is already using port 80.

You can kill it using:

`sudo fuser -k 80/tcp`

And then try restarting nginx again:

`service nginx start`

reference: https://easyengine.io/tutorials/nginx/troubleshooting/emerg-bind-failed-98-address-already-in-use